# Youtube API blocked in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, youtube-api, phonegap

I tried to load Youtube videos inside a cordova/phonegap app with the Youtube API v3, but the apps keeps saying the API isn't loaded.
Although it's working inside the PhoneGap development app, so it looks like a config problem or something.

The config.xml should have granted access to the API:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.3" />
```

And the index.html contains a securty meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ajax.googleapis.com apis.google.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

And the js code:

```
var checkYT = setInterval(function () {
  if(YT.loaded){
    clearInterval(checkYT);
  }
}, 100);

window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
};

var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

I tried also the plugin CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer from JonSmart, but without any luck :(

I don't want iframes, because I want to keep own controls for the videos.

Comment: What does the browser error console report?

Comment: So you can get a console? You notified it's only wrong in the APK-file after the build?

Comment: Yes, you can connect your Android phone to your computer, open your app, and view the app console on your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

index.html should contain this security line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *  data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Comment: Is it safe to do that content="default-src * " ?